# Direct Access Stacking network filter driver before iphttpsinterface

Tags: networking, drivers, windows-8, direct-access

Is there any way I can stack up my NDIS filter driver on top of iphttpsinterface, which is a virtual tunnel adapter provided by Microsoft for Direct Access. 
With this, I would like network traffic from my NDIS driver to go as input to iphttpsinterface rather than getting the output of iphttpsinterface as input to my filter driver. 

Thanks in advance.